# Find for which $a$ and $n$ polynomial is divisible by $(x-1)^2$

Tags: polynomials

The problems states: For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$, polynomial $P(x)=x^n-ax^{n-1}+ax-1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^2$?

What I've tried:
If i put in $P(1)$, $a$ just cancels out, so from there it is obvious that $P(x)$ is divisible by $(x-1)$, but what about the other $(x-1)$? What shall I do in a scenario, such as this one, when there are multiple same roots of a polynomial (eg. $(x-1)^2$?

(Without using derivatives)

Comment: $x-1\mid P^\prime(x)$.

Comment: @youthdoo without using derivatives. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your last message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by noticing that $x-1 | P(x)$. Then one can do long division to get that $$P(x) = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + (1-a)(x^{n-2 } + \dots + x)+1)$$

Now we need the latter factor to be divisible by $x-1$. It is a simple diophantine to solve from here. Can you take it?

Answer (score 2):

**Rewrite, sans derivatives**
The problem only makes sense for integer $n$.

While you can use polynomial long division, this case is easier. Note:

$f(x)=x^n - 1 - a x(x^{n-2}-1)$

$x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}+\dots+1)$

$f(x)= (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}+\dots+1- a x((x-1)(x^{n-3} + x^{n-4}+\dots+1))$

$f(x)/(x-1) = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}+\dots+1- a x(x^{n-3} + x^{n-4}+\dots+1)$

The value of this at 1 is:

$n - a(n-2)$

So when that's 0, there's another root at 1.

You'll want to verify that this still makes sense for small $n$.

Comment: Please read the whole question, at the bottom I mentioned that derivatives shouldn't be used to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Ah, I was composing this prior to your update. I'll rewrite with another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Without derivative:

\begin{align}
P(x)&=x^n-1-ax(x^{n-2}-1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1)-ax(x-1)(x^{n-3}+x^{n-4}+\cdots+x+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+(1-a)x^{n-2}+(1-a)x^{n-3}+\cdots+(1-a)x+1)\\
&=(x-1)Q(x)
\end{align}
where $Q(x)= x^{n-1}+(1-a)x^{n-2}+(1-a)x^{n-3}+\cdots+(1-a)x+1)$

> If $(x-1)^2|P(x)$ then $Q(1)=0$